# Screen is cut in half, when there is movement

Tags: kubuntu, screen, hdmi

I run kubuntu on an small htpc. The PC is connected to my TV via HDMI. Everything is fine until there is some movement. One half of the screen is a little off. Like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmAXl.jpg)

The horizontal line, where the latency appears, moves after reboot, but is otherwise stable. I changed the cable, tried a difrent TV without any different result. This happens when I see a video or when the screensaver is playing.

I tried to change the videocodec, but maybe i didn't do it right.

I think, I need mostly some help, to describe my problem, so I can search for a solution.

Please, please, please help me somehow.

Edit: I don't know why you ask me about the flash player. I have this problem, when the screensaver is running, when I play video files like avi and so on and when I play a video game.

Comment: is that in a flash player? Offtop: http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/512/438/8b2.jpg